# Django url match #!

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

I have the following url being passed to Django url processor:

```
#!/guide/welcome
```

I can't seem to get a regular expression that works -- everything I try fails, and the default `url(r'^$', ...)` is used. I think my problem is I can't get it to match on the first 2 chars `#!`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't match the [part of url after the # hash mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier), as it's not passed to Django. It's completely a client-side thing.

Comment: I'm just wondering, did the answer solve your problem? If not, please share your solution with us to make this post complete. If yes, consider marking it as accepted, so that the others can rely on it.